# How to remove values in a column of dataframe by position?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with following values:

```
data = {'Type':['sama', 'samb', 'samc', 'samd'],
              'Annotation':["a|b|c|d||||j|s|,g|b|k|d||||j|s|o,c|j|k|m||||j|k|o",
              "g|b|k|d|e|||j|s|o",
              "g|b|k|d|||z|j|s|o,c|j|k|m||||g|s|o",
              "g|b|k|d|e|y|u|j|h|i"]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1
```

It looks as follows:

```
    Type    Annotation
0   sama    a|b|c|d||||j|s|,g|b|k|d||||j|s|o,c|j|k|m||||j|k|o
1   samb    g|b|k|d|e|||j|s|o
2   samc    g|b|k|d|||z|j|s|o,c|j|k|m||||g|s|o
3   samd    g|b|k|d|e|y|u|j|h|i
```

The `df1['Annotation']` has data that are separated by `comma`. The data contains 10 values separated by `|`.

I want to remove ceratin values in each data by position. Here I want to remove from position `3,6,7,8` so that the output looks like:

```
    Type    Annotation
0   sama    a|b|d||s|,g|b|d||s|o,c|jm||k|o
1   samb    g|b|d|e|s|o
2   samc    g|b|d||s|o,c|j|m||s|o
3   samd    g|b|d|e|h|i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom lambda function with split by `,`, then split by `|` and filter values not exist in `pos list`, last join by `|` and `,`:

```
pos = [3,6,7,8]
f = lambda x: ','.join('|'.join(z for i, z in enumerate(y.split('|')) if i + 1 not in pos)
                                  for y in x.split(','))
df1['Annotation'] = df1['Annotation'].apply(f)
print (df1)
   Type      Annotation
0  sama      a|b|d||s|,g|b|d||s|o,c|j|m||k|o
1  samb      g|b|d|e|s|o
2  samc      g|b|d||s|o,c|j|m||s|o
3  samd      g|b|d|e|h|i
```